# C Program that Removes Comments from a String

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers

I am attempting to remove all comments beginning with `/*` and ending with `*/` from a string, using C. I accomplish this by adding all characters that are not inside the comment tags to a string named `noComments`.

As of now, the program works as intended except for the fact that the first four characters of the output string are gibberish `≥p3v`. When attempting to find the cause of this issue, I found that the `noComments` string contains the `≥p3v` gibberish phrase at its creation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"

void removeComments(char ccx[]);

int main(void)
{
    char ccx[] = "/* This is a comment */ void do_stuff() {return 0;} /* comment */ int var = 0;";
    removeComments(ccx);
    return 0;
}

void removeComments(char ccx[])
{
    char noComments[strlen(ccx)];
    // puts(noComments); // This displays "≥p3v"
    int inComment = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ccx); ++i)
    {
        if (ccx[i] == '/' && ccx[i + 1] == '*')
        {
            inComment = 1;
            i += 2;
        }
        else if (ccx[i] == '*' && ccx[i + 1] == '/')
        {
            inComment = 0;
            i += 2;
        }

        if (!inComment)
        {
            strncat(noComments, &(ccx[i]), 1);
            // printf("%c", ccx[i]);
        }
    }
    puts(noComments);
}
```

Current Output: `≥p3v void do_stuff() {return 0;}  int var = 0;`

Desired Output:  `void do_stuff() {return 0;}  int var = 0;`

Comment: Watch out, you can easily go out of bounds in your function. As well as `noComments` being to small if there's no comments in the input. And you never initialize `noComments` which means you can't use it as destination in `strncat`.

Comment: Besides that, please learn how to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Lastly about the "gibberish", that's because of the uninitialized `noComments` array. Uninitialized local non-static variables will have *indeterminate* values or contents. Always initialize your variables before attempting to use their values.

Comment: What about this string `"void dostuff() { printf (\"comment: open /*\\n\"); printf (\"comment close: */\\n\"); }"`?

Comment: You never initialize `noComments`. The `strncat` function requires a pointer to a string as its first parameter. On the first all, `noComments` is not a pointer to a string.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Here you have "naive" function. No nested comments.

```
#define COMMENT_START   "/*"
#define COMMENT_END   "*/"

char *removeComment(char *str)
{
    char *start, *end;

    start = strstr(str, COMMENT_START);
    if(start)
    {
        end = strstr(start + 2, COMMENT_END);
        if(end)
        {
            memmove(start, end + 2, strlen(end + 2) + 1);
        }
    }
    if(end && start) return str;
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "/* This is a comment */ void do_stuff() {return 0;} /* comment */ int var = 0;";

    while(removeComment(str));

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Downvote because it comes without explanation of the OP's mistake. Providing nothing but a bunch of code is frowned upon. (I'm not trying to be mean, just stating what I think is the case. Correct me if I'm wrong.) I'd also think the OP's approach is sound; why not provide the simple fix it needs (set the first byte in noComments to zero and make the string one char larger)? That would be much more helpful for the OP than to provide a totally unrelated solution.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica OPs function does not remove comments (does not return stripped version). That code was bad enough to completely replace it.